# What does "any one person" mean?

Tags: meaning

It is from this [article](https://www.healthline.com/nutrition/fruit-and-low-carb#section2). Here is the context:

> Whether **any one person** can or should include fruit in their diet depends on a lot of things.

What I cannot get is the use of the word *one* there. What did the author use it for?

Answer (score 2):

**one person** is being used there as a synonym for **individual**.

> [Whether any individual](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=whether+any+one+person%2Cwhether+any+individual&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cwhether%20any%20one%20person%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cwhether%20any%20individual%3B%2Cc0) can or should include fruit in their diet depends on a lot of things.

Comment: Is there any difference between "person" and "individual"?

Comment: There can be shades of difference, yes.  *Individual* asserts a uniqueness that *person* does not, hence "any *one* person". And some speakers will even feel that *individual* does not assert uniqueness strongly enough and thus say *any unique individual*, which other speakers would consider pleonasm.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the author tries to emphasize this fact that each person, individually has to conform to special rules. And each case should be investigated according to special circumstances because he or she might have dietary restrictions, food allergies and other factors and influences that are not true about the others.

I personally think the **"one"** can be removed, but it is there to emphasize.